# Java. Найти байт или байты с максимальным количеством повторов в файле

Tags: java

Здравствуйте,натолкните на верную мысль пожалуйста, никак не могу решить задачу.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Integer>bytes=new LinkedList<>();
        List<Integer>max_bytes=new LinkedList<>();
        String fileName = "e:/f.txt";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        while (is.available() > 0) {
            bytes.add(is.read());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < bytes.size(); j++)
                if (bytes.get(i)==bytes.get(j)) {
                    max_bytes.add(bytes.get(i));
                    break;
                }

        }
        System.out.println(bytes);//Первый массив
        System.out.println(max_bytes);//Массив с повторяющимся байтами.
    }
```

Вывод программы:

[53, 13, 10, 56, 13, 10, 49, 49, 13, 10, 51, 13, 10, 50, 13, 10, 49, 48]

[13, 10, 13, 10, 49, 49, 13, 10, 13, 10]

Тоесть куда-то теряется по одному числу из повторяющихся.

Вывод тестовый просто чтоб убедиться что он добавляет только повторющиеся. 
Мне нужно вывести найболее частые повторы: 13 10 49.

Comment: А что вы узнали после использования отладчика?

Comment: Жуть то какая. А не проще сделать массив из 256 элементов, изначально равных 0 и для каждого встреченного байта просто увеличивать на 1 элемент массива с индексом соответствующим этому байту ?

Comment: @Mike, называется сортировка подсчетом. Хороший сопособ для этой задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный алгоритм для такого типа задач таков: Создаем массив счетчиков для каждого элемента, где индексом будет сам элемент, а значением будет количество вхождений элемента. Такой алгоритм всегда эффективен, если количество элементов, которые нужно посчитать невелико. Простые пример: байты, буквы алфавита.

То есть сделайте так примерно:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] bytes = new int[255];
    String fileName = "e:/f.txt";
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    byte b;
    while (true) {
        b = (byte)is.read();
        if(b == -1) break;
        bytes[b]++;
    }
}
```

P.S. метод available() не предназначен для определения конца потока, для этого нужно проверять значение, которое вернул read()

Comment: Вы код-то проверяли? Он как бы не работает.

Comment: исправил. но главное что автор вопроса суть понял.